# 500 Internal Server Error when Regex fails in C# data annotation asp.net core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I added a Regular Express on a model property using data annotation to validate date string. It works fine when date string is a valid date {dd/mm/yyyy}, but returns 500 internal server error when an invalid date string is entered.

I want to do the validation by checking if `ModelState` is valid instead of using `DateTime.TryParse`. Below is my code snippet

```
[RegularExpression(@"(((0?|1)[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/((19|20)\d\d))$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid date format. Date should be in this format {dd/mm/yyyy}")]
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Regular Expressions are not a reliable way to check for proper input in this case. [DateTime.TryPrase()][1] would be the proper way. No amount of trying to immitate the rules with a Regex, will beat actually applying the rules with Parsing.  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse

Comment: I also notice that the error happens for other validations. Once the regex fails, it returns 500 internal server error

Comment: I have figured out why I am having the error. Seems dotnet core is trying to evaluate `{dd/mm/yyyy}` in the ErrorMessage value. I removed the curly braces and it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out why I was having the error. Seems dotnet core is trying to evaluate {dd/mm/yyyy} in the ErrorMessage value. I removed the curly braces and it is fine.

I changed

```
[RegularExpression(@"(((0?|1)[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/((19|20)\d\d))$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid date format. Date should be in this format {dd/mm/yyyy}")]
```

to

```
[RegularExpression(@"(((0?|1)[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\/((19|20)\d\d))$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid date format. Date should be in dd/mm/yyyy format")]
```

Comment: Thank you for posting your solution. I had curly braces in my error message and ran into the same problem. I may have never figured out why!